# Select element that's before the element containing certain linkText

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, xpath

Using selenium I'm trying to click a `<td>` element that appears just before the `<td>` element that has linkText of "Main". I'm trying to click the highlighted element in this image:

[image: screen]

Both the `<td>` element I want to click and the one after it are within the same `<tr>` element, shown in the image as having `id=5`.

This  element corresponds to the **entire** row highlighted below. Notice how its linkText is "Green" just like the element beneath it. Therefore I can't use an xpath/css selector for the `<td>` element I want to click.

[image]

I'm trying to click the highlighted "Green". That's why I'm trying to click the `<td>` element **before** the element with "Main" as its linkText.

I have this code but I don't know how to get the element before the element this code matches:  `WebElement templateFound = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Main"));`

Anything helps, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`following-sibling` axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling):

```
//td[following-sibling::td[1]/a = 'Main']
```

Basically, this would give you a `td` element that has a link with text "Main" inside the first following `td` sibling.

---

Or, once you've located the link by link text, you can use [`preceding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding), which would give you the first preceding `td` element except the parent `td` element:

> The preceding axis indicates all the nodes that precede the context
>   node in the document except any ancestor, attribute and namespace
>   nodes.

```
WebElement templateFound = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Main"));
templateFound.findElement(By.xpath("preceding::td"));
```

Comment: Thanks alecxe, `preceding::td` might be working but its selecting the entire `td` element but instead I need to click it's child `a` element. My apologies. So I tried to use `templateFound.findElement(By.xpath("preceding::td/a"));` but it still clicks the entire `td`. Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: @Hurmle the expression looks correct and should match the `a` element inside the `td`. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks alecxe, I'm trying your first suggestions of `//td[following-sibling::td[1]/a = 'Main']` but this selects the `td` element instead of `a` link, which contains 'Green'. How do I adapt this expression so it only selects the `a`. Try yourself: [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/9a6b90f8859651d1633f2c33d14d39b8)

Comment: @JimJim sure, it's just `//td[following-sibling::td[1]/a = 'Main']/a`.

Comment: Yep, you got it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy with XPATH. I assume the `td` you want to select has the text *Green*

```
//a[.='Main']/../../td[.='Green']
```

Comment: I suspect there is an `a` element that has the "Green" text..may be it should be `//a[.='Main']/../../td[a='Green']` or `//a[.='Main']/../../td/a[.='Green']` instead..

Comment: Thanks Saifur. Is this xpath just as reliable as alecxe's answer of `preceding::td`. Your answer seems like it involves more components, which could potentially cause issues. Excuse me if I'm wrong, thanks.